# Does calling system.exit() in a AWS ECS Service cause a Task (manager by a service) to be restarted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

If a java process that I own calls System.exit(1) and I have a task with a Docker file that runs a java process (see below), will the task be restarted by ECS assuming that I have a cluster running a service (where the service runs the task)? A snippet from my docker file:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Xmx600m","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Only if the container is marked "essential" within the task.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jordanm! Per Jordan's answer "Only if the container is marked "essential" within the task."